# OAuth User Table customise

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented Oauth2 in my spring boot application.

I have user table as below:

[image: User Table]

So when I am hitting:

[image]

Authentication of username and password is being done through user table.
But in my application, I already have a another user table, so I want to remove the username and password from the table above and want to use my existing table only for authentication. Is it possible?

User table in my application:
TABLE--> user_details

Columns: username, password

Is it possible in oauth, like only authentication to be done from my own table and rest of the details to be taken from authdb.user?
Or else is it possible we can remove enabled, accountNotExpired,..other columns?

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security, the UserDetailsService interface is responsible for loading user detail information，JdbcDaoImpl is default implementation for JDBC.
All you need to do is to create a subclass of JdbcDaoImpl and override loadUsersByUsername method that load user detail from table user and table user_details.
Don't forget declare your subclass as a Bean in security config class like this

```
@Configuration
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   //other method
  
    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomJdbcDaoImpl();
    }
}
```